# django url reverse not working for named urls (re-edited) found the cause but now stuck!

Tags: django, django-admin, django-urls

See bottom for latest break throughs:
I'm running django SVN 15632

`Tried viewHallo in module core.views. Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'viewHallo'`

is the error I am getting after trying `reverse('home')` or `reverse('admin:index')`.

this is my projects urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.views import serve as serveStatic

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/',   include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^dbrowse/', include('dbrowse.urls')),
    (r'^static/',  serveStatic),
url (r'^$',    'core.views.viewHallo',name='home'),
)
```

this is core\views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template.context import RequestContext
import site

def viewHallo (request):
    pass
    return render_to_response ('core.html',
                               {'site':site,
                                'title':'i am the hallo view',
                                'content':'Hallo World!',},
                                context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

using the shell or even a script `reverse('home')` and `reverse('admin:index')` just isn't working.

However in my templates `{% url home %}` and {% url admin:index %} work just fine...

in my app `core` i have a file called `site.py` i use this file to store stuff about the site so i dont have to rely on the database. long story short it contains `reverse('home')`. Now this is only important because no matter where `reverse()` is excecuted script or shell or template, the stack trace always includes the line from `site.py`.

why on earth is django excecuting `site.py`? and even if it does why is it stumbling over the `reverse('home')`?. Interstingly if I comment out the line from `site.py` then `reverse()` starts working properly.

whats going on?? here is `core\site.py`

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

site = Site.objects.get(pk=settings.SITE_ID)

NAME = site.name
SLOGAN = 'it\'s a deal!'
COPY_HOLDER = 'My Name'


#(link_title, 'link_address', ['permission'])
MAIN_MENU = [['home', reverse('home'), 'core.view_tender'],
             ['admin', reverse('admin:index'), 'is_staff']]
```

---

EDIT: I have isolated the line in django's source code that's throwing the error:
line 91 in `django/core/urlresolvers.py`

`91: lookup_view = getattr(import_module(mod_name), func_name)`
it triggers django `importlib` which in turn imports `site.py`.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few problems here.

`reverse('home')` should work exactly how you have it but your error is happening before reverse can complete. We've got to sort out the URL conf issues first.

Does `core.views.viewHallo` actually exist?

---

For the admin urls, `name=` will not work because it is an include (which doesn't have a specific url, it just points to another url conf, so `reverse('admin')` wouldn't work).

The admin urls have a namespace, and namespaced urls are reversed with `namespace:named_url`
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces

You say it's the *only* thing that works -- what else are you trying to do? To reverse other admin urls, there is a specific syntax outlined here: 
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls

```
url = reverse('admin:app_model_change')
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: i dint know that you couldn't name urls with include, good point!. But strange that it stopped all other `reverse()` methods resolving. But thanks, I'm back on the road!

Comment: sorry I assumed that because {% url home %} was working, then reverse('home') should work too. so no I'm still stuck. So I've re-edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are importing the `site` module before the function `viewHallo` is defined.  The error message is quite correct - at the time `reverse` is being called, the module has no such member `viewHallo`.  Normally, the module would be loaded up when needed and everything would be fine, but in this case, the module is *already in the process of being loaded*.  It's a case of having a cyclic dependency between Python modules.